# Where do you set the "maven.plugin.validation" property?

Tags: maven

I've just upgraded to Maven 3.9.2, and at the end of my build I get the warning:

```
Plugin validation issues were detected in 4 plugin(s)

 * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.5.0
 * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
 * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.20.0
 * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0

For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
```

However, it doesn't tell me *where* I should set that property!

I've tried in my pom.xml file itself:

```
  <properties>    
    <maven.plugin.validation>verbose</maven.plugin.validation>
  </properties>
```

...but that seems to make no difference. In fact, it seems to be completely ignore, since setting it to an invalid value doesn't get noticed (according to [maven's own code](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.2/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/internal/DefaultPluginValidationManager.html) it should raise a warning).

I'm obviously missing something, but have run out of ideas on what to search for to find it! Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can define a property using the following option on the command line:

```
-Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE
```

This is the option most frequently used to customize Maven plugins' behavior. You could trigger the install action, for example:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo - so it's not possible to do it from within Maven then? As I'm using the Netbeans IDE, it would be easier if I didn't have to trundle off to Tools - Options - Java - Maven (and then remember to remove it again for other projects!)

Comment: I would assume you should be able to set it in the properties section at your pom.xml. For some reason using Maven 3.9.2, it only works if you provide your settings via command line argument, ignoring if you set the property in the pom.xml

Comment: you can set it also in `${project.root}/.mvn/jvm.config`

Answer (score 4):

`maven.plugin.validation` property is used by Maven itself, so it can not be configured in project `pom.xml`

As mentioned in previous answer it can be set on command line.

It can be also added to project file `.mvn/maven.config` - so you can have configuration on project level.

It can also be added to properties in `~/.m2/settings.xml` and you will have configuration on system level.

There is example of `settings.xml`

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd">

    <!-- properties can be defined only in profile, so create one -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>properties</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.plugin.validation>VERBOSE</maven.plugin.validation>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <!-- profile with properties must be activated with a static way -->
        <activeProfile>properties</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Please consult: [Plugin Validation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugins/validation/index.html)

Comment: Have you made it work by adding in `.m2/settings.xml`?
If so, in what tag and in what format have you exactly set the property? I've tried several things, but none has worked.

Comment: @vaha I added example of settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't edit the maven configuration files for this because it is an option to be used temporarily in a specific situation in one project.

In IntelliJ, you can create an extra run/debug configuration and place it in the Run/Debug configuration dialog in the "Run" field before specifying the target.
Example:

```
-Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE processor:process -f pom.xml
```