# Plugin validation issues were detected in plugin(s)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

After executing `mvn clean verify` everything compiles properly with success, but also I get the following:

```
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 7 plugin(s)
[WARNING] 
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2
[WARNING]  * org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
[WARNING]  * org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.3.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2
[WARNING]  * com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
```

Firstly, I don't understand the warning itself, its affection on my code, etc.
Then how to fix that? And lastly, how to use `maven.plugin.validation` property? I couldn't find any docs about this.

Comment: It's a new feature, introduced here https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.2/release-notes.html | Seems like it is a warning about the plugins not being support by the upcoming Maven 4. To fix you should update the plugins to their new versions which support Maven 4, if they get such a release

Comment: And there's no option to turn off the validation report. The only way to not show the validation report is to fix all validation issues.

Comment: Most of those warnings (except for jacoco and for this apt-maven-plugin I'm not sure about too old from my perspective?) can simply being removed by updating your plugin versions to the most recent versions  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: my opinions are only getting worse as it clearly contains the "you can upgrade this POM" assumption which doesn't apply to building old branches, third party libs etc.  I'm debating rolling back the last upgrade and pinning it in homebrew

Comment: Similar: [*What are "Plugin validation issues" reported by Maven after running a JavaFX app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76760472/642706)

Answer (score 19):

It's a new feature to warn you that some plugin you are using may not work in future. You can make a lot quieter by using the brief mode, though it never goes away completely.

```
mvn package -Dmaven.plugin.validation=brief
```

You can set this in the MAVEN_ARGS environment variable and have it picked up everywhere, so apart from a warning "some plugins are out of date" you aren't distracted

```
export MAVEN_ARGS="-Dmaven.plugin.validation=brief"
```

Answer (score 16):

tl;dr - Try Upgrading Maven. Worked for me.

I was getting these two Warnings ...

```
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0
```

... and I did not have either plugin configured in my POM. So I assumed that my installation of Maven was using older versions of those plugins automatically; I confirmed at Maven Central that both plugins had newer versions than the above; and I upgraded Maven from 3.9.2 -> 3.9.3. Now I get no warnings, even though my POM is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, it looks like plugin validation was "toned down" in 3.93: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.3/release-notes.html

Answer (score 5):

Introduced in maven 3.9.x the maven validator shows you plugins that are not maven 4.x compatible. As long as you stay below maven 4.x there will be no impact to your build.

There are two types of reported plugins

### Internal

- using deprecated plugins goals
- using deprecated plugins parameters
- using read only plugins parameters

-> users can fix their project by fixing configuration by editing their POMs. Users should consult actual plugin documentation or try to update plugin to newer version.

### External

- using old, deprecated Maven Api by plugin
- declaring dependencies for Maven Core artifacts in wrong scope in plugin project

-> only fixable by maintainer

### Remove message

To remove the message all together you can set locally

```
mvn -Dmaven.plugin.validation=none
```

> Can be added to MAVEN_OPTS or MAVEN_ARGS environment variables, can
> also be added to .mvn/maven.config file in order to configure per
> project.
>
> Users can add such property to their settings.xml file to change
> configuration globally.
>
> NOTICE as maven.plugin.validation is configuration item for Maven
> itself, it can not be used in project pom.xml

Other case insensitive options are as listed in the [maven validator documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugins/validation/index.html):

- NONE - mute Plugin Validation completely, nothing will be reported
- INLINE - report only Internal issues in place where occur
- BRIEF - report only Internal issues in place where occur and list of plugins
  with External issues at the and of build
- SUMMARY - report list of
  plugins with Internal and External issues at the end of build
- VERBOSE - report Internal and External issues at the end of build in verbose mode

Answer (score 1):

The second answer in the following stackoverflow question url solves the problem in a better way using a settings.xml that resides in the .m2 directory.

[Where do you set the "maven.plugin.validation" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252691/where-do-you-set-the-maven-plugin-validation-property)

There is example of settings.xml

```
<!-- properties can be defined only in profile, so create one -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>properties</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.plugin.validation>BRIEF</maven.plugin.validation>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <!-- profile with properties must be activated with a static way -->
    <activeProfile>properties</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Java version from 8 to 17. Worked for reasons i dont know

Comment: Did that. Didn't work for me. : (