# What are "Plugin validation issues" reported by Maven after running a JavaFX app?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, warnings

I created a new JavaFX/[OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) project using the [JavaFX template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) offered by [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDEA 2023.2 RC. Using version 20 of both Java & JavaFX.

When running my app from the *Maven* panel within IntelliJ, choosing *Plugins > javafx > javafx:run*, after I quit the app I get these warnings in the console panel of IntelliJ:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 2 plugin(s)
[WARNING] 
[WARNING]  * org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING]
```

Note that these warnings do not appear on the console until *after* quitting the execution of my app.

What is the meaning of these warnings? How to resolve them?

The first is the latest version. The second is nearly the latest, 3.3.0 versus the latest being 3.3.1. So I presume versioning is not the problem.

As suggested by the warnings, I tried defining that property within the POM. But doing so had no effect. I do not see any additional details in the console.

```xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.plugin.validation>VERBOSE</maven.plugin.validation>
    </properties>
```

I found the existing Question, [*Plugin validation issues were detected in plugin(s)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76355897/642706). But none of the Answers seem relevant to my situation.

[Web searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5BWARNING%5D%20Plugin%20validation%20issues%20were%20detected%20in%202%20plugin(s)%20%5BWARNING%5D%20%20%5BWARNING%5D%20%20*%20org.openjfx%3Ajavafx-maven-plugin%3A0.0.8%20%5BWARNING%5D%20%20*%20org.apache.maven.plugins%3Amaven-resources-plugin%3A3.3.0&t=osx&ia=web) did not surface any helpful info.

---

I slightly modified the POM to look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.voters</groupId>
    <artifactId>voters_wa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Voters WA</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.plugin.validation>VERBOSE</maven.plugin.validation>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.voters.voters_wa/work.basil.voters.voters_wa.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The property should be used in command line. For more details, please check the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252691/where-do-you-set-the-maven-plugin-validation-property

Answer (score 3):

Property `maven.plugin.validation` can not be set in project `pom.xml` it is used by Maven internally.

`maven-resources-plugin` was fixed in version 3.3.1

Please consult the *Apache Maven* documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugins/validation/index.html

Answer (score 2):

This was tricky for me to replicate. To do it, in addition to the instructions in the question:

- I used Idea 2023.1.4 Ultimate Edition
- changed my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the OpenJDK 20.0.2 installation.

  - the javafx-maven-plugin run command used the java version from `JAVA_HOME` which I originally had at 17, not that configured in Idea, so that gave class version mismatches as the Maven pom.xml provided requires to use only Java 20+.
- changed the idea configuration to use the Maven version from the project maven wrapper rather than the inbuilt version from idea.
- changed the Maven version in the project/.mvn/maven-wrapper.properties to:

  ```
  distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.9.3/apache-maven-3.9.3-bin.zip
  ```

  - versions older than 3.9 don't perform plugin validation and the default in my maven wrapper properties was a 3.8.x version.
- Refreshed the maven project.
- Right clicked on `javafx:run` in the maven panel.
- Modified the Run configuration, set the run command to:

  ```
  -Dmaven.plugin.validation=verbose javafx:run -f pom.xml
  ```
- Ran the new configuration.

I received a warning in the output after completing the run:

```
[WARNING]  * org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8
[WARNING]   Plugin EXTERNAL issue(s):
[WARNING]    * Plugin mixes multiple Maven versions: [3.3.9, 3.6.0]
[WARNING]    * Plugin should declare Maven artifacts in `provided` scope. If the plugin already declares them in `provided` scope, update the maven-plugin-plugin to latest version. Artifacts found with wrong scope: [org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.6.0]
```

So it would appear to be a warning about an issue with `javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8` (that doesn't appear to affect its actual operation).  Perhaps a bug or issue report could be filed for the plugin developers to request them to address the warning.

The warning regarding `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0` did not occur for me, as my setup was already using `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1`, which is noted as fixed in [Slawomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76760970/1155209).

For more info on plugin validation, as noted by Slawomir, see:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugins/validation/index.html